# programmatically load repository workspace components into local workspace

Tags: java, rtc

i'm retriving my repository workspace **programatically** with this snippet:

```
IWorkspaceManager workspaceManager = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(teamRepository);
IWorkspaceSearchCriteria wsSearchCriteria = WorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
wsSearchCriteria.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.WORKSPACES);
wsSearchCriteria.setExactOwnerName("ownerName"); //replaced with real parameter
List<IWorkspaceHandle> workspaceHandles = workspaceManager.findWorkspaces(wsSearchCriteria,Integer.MAX_VALUE, monitor);

 //so, here i got my repWorkSpace:
IRepositoryWorkspace myDesiredRepositoryWorkspace = workspaceHandles.get(0);
```

how can i **programatically fetch/load** components from the repository workspace into my eclipse workspace?

you can get your components by this snippet:

```
List<IComponent> componentList = new ArrayList<IComponent>();
for(Object componentHandle: myDesiredRepositoryWorkspace.getComponents() ){
    IItemHandle handle = (IItemHandle) componentHandle;
    IItemManager itemManager = teamRepository.itemManager();
    IComponent component = (IComponent) itemManager.fetchCompleteItem(handle, IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor );
    componentList.add(component);
}
```

after that i have my repository workspace, i have all components from each workspace but i'm not able to load the repository workspace into a local workspace.

i'm developint a eclipse plugin, so you'll need the following plugins (or imports from the plain-java-api directly):

- com.ibm.team.rtc.common
- com.ibm.team.repository.client
- com.ibm.team.scm.client
- com.ibm.team.scm.common
- com.ibm.team.process.common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, loading works with `ILoadRule2`, i found a way, but sadly it involves a bypass via xml-files. It requires access to the sandbox, but it's all described below ^_^

let's assume we have our workspace and our components (as mentioned in the question), we can load the workspace with this snippet:

```
ISharingManager sharingManager = FileSystemCore.getSharingManager();
File workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toFile();                               
PathLocation pathlocation = new PathLocation(workspaceRoot.getAbsolutePath());
ILocation sandBoxLocation = pathlocation.getCanonicalForm();
ISandbox sandbox = sharingManager.getSandbox(sandBoxLocation, false);
LoadDilemmaHandler p = LoadDilemmaHandler.getDefault();

monitor.subTask("searching for load rules file");

File f = LoadRuleUtility.createLoadRules(componentList);
InputStream ins = new FileInputStream(f);
Reader xmlReader = new InputStreamReader(ins);
ILoadRule2 rule = ILoadRuleFactory.loadRuleFactory.getLoadRule(con, xmlReader, monitor);                                    
ILoadOperation loadoperator = rule.getLoadOp(sandbox, p, monitor);
monitor.subTask("loading files from RTC server...");
loadoperator.run(monitor);
```

ok, the magic of `LoadRuleUtility.createLoadRules()` is that it creates a xml file that describes the workspaces's components. (i'm using a DOM).

it has to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<scm:sourceControlLoadRule eclipseProjectOptions="import" version="1" xmlns:scm="http://com.ibm.team.scm">

    <!-- for each component in your repository workspace -->
    <parentLoadRule>
        <component name="component_name"/>
        <parentFolder repositoryPath="/"/>
    </parentLoadRule>

</scm:sourceControlLoadRule>
```

to **unload** the components you simply have to delete them:

```
IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
for(IProject project: projects){
    try {
        project.delete(true, true, monitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```